# tmux copy mode not working in ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, tmux, input-method, copy-and-paste

I want to copy the stdout in my tmux terminal, and I can't use mouse to copy because it will select to the other pane which I don't want it.

I goolge 'tmux copy' and found the solution as below :

1. `prefix + [` -> enter copy-mode
2. arrow key move cursor to the position I want
3. `ctrl + space` -> start select text

But I stuck with step3, when I press `ctrl + space`, it will become 'change input method', I also tried press `space` only but not working either.

Any help would be grateful.

The following content is my `.tmux.conf` file

```
set -g default-shell /bin/zsh
set -g window-style 'fg=colour247,bg=colour236'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour250,bg=black'

#pane border
set -g pane-border-bg colour235
set -g pane-border-fg colour238
set -g pane-active-border-bg colour236
set -g pane-active-border-fg colour51
```

Comment: For default tmux, just `space` is used to start selecting in copy mode. Please edit your post to provide the contents of your `.tmux.conf` file.

Comment: Provided. Thanks.

Comment: Ok try and rebind the key you want. Add the following lines to your `.tmux.conf`: `unbind -T copy-mode Space` and `bind -T copy-mode C-Space send-keys -X begin-selection` - see if that works. If not, try and bind "begin-selection" to another key, for instance: `bind -T copy-mode C-a send-keys -X begin-selection`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Restart or reload config of tmux first of course..

Comment: Hi, @ArturMeinild, thanks for your help, I added the lines you said and reload the config file, but it keep shows an error `table copy-mode doesn't exist`, and of course, text selection still not working.

Comment: Hmm it must be because it's an older tmux version, that something is not supported.

Comment: So I have to update my tmux and retry these line into my config?

Comment: That's an option yeah. It's for certain that I cannot help with a tmux version that is 4 years old. I'm not sure if dependencies will be affected if you just install the latest .deb package. There is also a snap version of tmux that you could try.